# Lambda and modifySpotFleetRequest

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I have a lambda function which I want to modify the capacity of a spotFeel Request. Whenever I run the function in aws it doesn't seem to do anything, no errors happen.

```js
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

dotenv.config();

AWS.config.update({ region: process.env.AWS_WORK_REGION });
AWS.config.apiVersions = { ec2: '2016-11-15' };

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
 const ec2 = new AWS.EC2();

  try {
    const terminationParams = {
      SpotFleetRequestId: '<SpotFleetRequestId>',
      TargetCapacity: 1,
    };

    console.log(terminationParams);

    ec2.modifySpotFleetRequest(terminationParams, function (err, data) {
      console.log('here');
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error('Error', JSON.stringify(err));
  }
};
```

The console.logs inside modifySpotFleetRequest don't seem to work.

If I move the code into a file I can run locally everything seems to work as expected.

My lambda role has the correct permissions from what I can see.

Any ideas?

Comment: could you try to add `await` before `ec2.modifySpotFleetRequest....` and `.promise()` at the end of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Ersoy suggested worked:

```js
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

dotenv.config();

AWS.config.update({ region: process.env.AWS_WORK_REGION });
AWS.config.apiVersions = { ec2: '2016-11-15' };

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
 const ec2 = new AWS.EC2();

  try {
    const terminationParams = {
      SpotFleetRequestId: '<SpotFleetRequestId>',
      TargetCapacity: 1,
    };

    console.log(terminationParams);

    await ec2.modifySpotFleetRequest(terminationParams, function (err, data) {
      console.log('here');
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(data);
      }
    }).promise();
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error('Error', JSON.stringify(err));
  }
};
```